# Bitcoin arbitrage, what do exchange office alows you to cash out?

Tags: arbitrage

I am wondering, if I do BTC arbitrage, meaning I buy BTC in one exchange, send to a second exchange and sell for FIAT, does the second exchange have any problems with me doing this? Because I will be only using them to sell  my BTC, so I will be cashing out a huge amount of money every month.

What is your opinion on using exchange office just to cash out?  And what do you think, they let you cash out monthly?

Answer (score 0):

Every exchange has its own rules, but generally they allow you to import bitcoin from any source and sell it. Where they tend to differ greatly is the amount that they will let you withdraw to your bank account either daily or weekly. For example, gdax/Coinbase greatly reduces the amount you can withdraw if your account is not verified, meaning, you need to upload identity documents. I believe they limit you to $1000 per day, buy/sell, and additionally limit you to $1000 per day withdraw. However, if verified, buy/sell is unlimited and withdraw is $50,000 per week.